# batch to rename multiple files

Tags: batch-file

I have some files that I need to rename and as the volume is quite big, I was thinking of using a batch file since all I need to do is:

```
u_ex140429.log >> u_ex140429_01.log
```

But all the codes I found either place the _01 at the beginning or at the end of the file:

`_01u_ex140429.log` or `u_ex140429.log_01`

If there is a thread somewhere here about this, I do apologize for I have been looking for quite a while.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using this.

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*.*) do (move %%f %%~nf_01%%~xf )
```

[technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx)

Comment: This has an unneeded `backslash` and can cause files to be renamed more than once, due to a bug in a plain `for in do` (some new files with the same filespec are processed again).  A `for /f` loop is reliable for this task.

Answer (score 0):

This adds `_01` before the extension of each `.txt` filename in the current folder without the limitation of a plain `for-in-do` command.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.txt /b /a-d ') do ren "%%a" "%%~na_01%%~xa"
```

Answer (score -1):

a for loop works just fine ...

```
@echo off

dir /b ¦ find /v /c "*">filescount.txt

for /f %%f in (filescount.txt) do (
  for /L %%n in (1 1 %%f) do (
    for %%a in (*.*) do (
      rename "%%a" "%%~na_%%n%%~xa"
    )
  )
)
```

place the batch file in the directory containing your files to be renamed

Comment: This will not work as asked - and just a pointer here that the pipe character is also an issue as it's not the correct ascii value.  Type it from your keyboard and it should be fine.